# Was sind eigentlich "verknorpelte Gespenster" in diesem Auszug aus dem Roman "die Blechtrommel"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Er knotet ordinäre Bindfäden, die er nach den Besuchsstunden in den Zimmern seiner Patienten sammelt und entwirrt, zu vielschichtig verknorpelten Gespenstern, taucht diese dann in Gips, läßt sie erstarren und spießt sie mit Stricknadeln, die auf Holzsöckelchen befestigt sind.

Laut Duden hat das Verb *verknorpeln* eine medizinische Bedeutung, und zwar "zu Knorpel werden". Wie können denn aus ordinären Bindfäden geknotete Gespenster *verknorpelt* sein?

Answer (score 3):

Ich vermute, dass Grass mit "verknorpelt" das Aussehen der Gespenster beschreibt:

Die Bindfäden werden geknotet, und diese Knoten ähneln rein optisch den Knorpeln z.B. an einem Gicht- geplagten Gelenk oder auch an einem abgenagten Hühnerbein.

Ich vermute, diese optische Ähnlichkeit soll durch den Begriff "verknorpelt" zum Ausdruck gebracht werden.

Comment: Vergleiche z.B. auch die gefaltete Form des Ohrknorpels.

Answer (score 0):

Grass wollte vermutlich einen Unterschied zu den heutzutage allgemein bekannten **verknöcherten** Gespenstern darstellen. Wobei das natürlich alles Unsinn ist, denn tradionell haben Gespenster gar keinen Leib, sind nur Schein, Nebel, Irrlicht.